# XMPPFramework integration with Swift

Tags: xcode, xmppframework

I have successfully integrate the XMPPFramework by pods with Swift language. When I try to build a project I found some errors. I have searched a lot but does not found any solution. Kindly help me out to fix this issue.

[image]